# How to Initialize Win32 HANDLE appropriately?

Tags: winapi, handle

Is it OK to initialize the Win32 `HANDLE` to `NULL`? Or are there any better or recommended way to initialize `HANDLE`s?

For example,

```
void foo()
{
   HANDLE hFile;
   hFile = CreateFile(/* necessary arguments*/);
}
```

What shall i initialize the `hFile` with?

Comment: You should initialize it with the return value of CreateFile().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example code you don't need to initialise `hFile` to anything since it is initialised by the `CreateFile` function.

The Windows API is not completely consistent on what it considers a "null" handle. Some APIs (like `CreateFile`) return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure, whereas others return `NULL` on failure. So the way you test if a `HANDLE` is valid or not depends on the function you are getting it from - check the actual documentation for the function and see what it says is the return value on failure.